Importing function from another ReactJS component
I have a component that contains a function:
const Component1 = () => {

    function exampleFunction(){
        // function code here
    }
}

export default Component1;

Component1 is imported by  other components so I default export it as above.
I'm trying to import it in component2 but I get an error saying:
export 'exampleFunction' (imported as 'function') was not found in './component1' (possible exports: default)

import { exampleFunction } from './component1';

const Component2 = () => {

   return(
      <div>{exampleFunction()}</div>
   ); 

}

export default Component2;


This function doesn't even exist at this point

Move exampleFunction() out of Component1 so it's a top-level function in the component1 file, and export it.
export function exampleFunction() {
    // function code here
}

const Component1 = () => {

}

export default Component1


